# axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a[method] is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm getting above error when I make a request to backend. I have similar code on another project, there is no issue. but here it's causing problems

my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default function apiCall(method, path, data) {
    console.log(method, url, data); 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return axios[method](path, data)
                .then(res => {
                    return resolve(res.data);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                    reject(err)
                });
    });
}
```

api call function

```
apiCall('POST', `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/`, {standard, subject, totalMarks, totalQuestions} )
        .then(data =>{
            console.log(data);

        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
            return this.props.addError(err.message)

        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention to the fact that objects in javascript are case sensitive, therefore, accessing `obj['post']` and `obj['POST']` will return different values.

axios has method `get`, `post` etc, as **lowercase**, you are trying to access them via **uppercase**, therefore u getting an undefined value.

You can fix that by converting the method variable to **lowercase**.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function apiCall(method, path, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return axios[method.toLowerCase()](path, data)
                .then(res => {
                    return resolve(res.data);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                    reject(err)
                });
    });
}
```

BTW, axios methods are already returning `Promises`, so you can make your code a bit simpler by using it.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function apiCall(method, path, data) {
    return axios[method.toLowerCase()](path, data)
           .then(res => res.data)
           .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                return Promise.reject(err);
           });
}
```

Comment: thanks @felixmosh. now i'm getting another error. `DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL`. i have double checked the url, method and data. all are fine.
my console.log response : `post https://d52890213a1XXXXXXaab4e.vfs.cloud9.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:8080'/api/questions {standard: "VIII", subject: "geography", totalMarks: "15", totalQuestions: "3"}`

Comment: Looks like your url is wrong, you have an `'` after the port number https://d52890213a1XXXXXXaab4e.vfs.cloud9.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:8080'/api/questions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and felixmosh gave me the key

```
const { data } = await axios.PUT(
     `/api/users/profile/update/`,
     user,
     config
     )
```

I fixed it changing the method and it worked to me ;)

```
const { data } = await axios.put(
     `/api/users/profile/update/`,
     user,
     config
     )
```